# remove parameters from Code Editor Dropdown in VS2019 IDE

Tags: vb.net, ide, editor

I have upgraded from VS2013 to VS2019. I noticed that all the parameters appear in the Code Editor dropdown as shown here:

[image]

How can I remove them from the dropdown? These did not appear in VS2013. I have looked for the setting and even tried to match the settings from VS2013 but they still appear. Any suggestions?

I have updated this question to show what it looks like in VS2013 as well.
[image]

Comment: They're not parameters. They're fields. That drop-down is supposed to display all the members of the currently selected type and they are members, so they get displayed. That whole strip is called the Navigation Bar because it allows you to navigate directly to any member, etc. How could you navigate to a member that wasn't there? I suggest that you get over it. If they weren't displayed in earlier VS versions (which I don't recall being the case but it's been a long time) then that was a deficiency in those earlier versions.

Comment: If you click in `Sub1_Test()`, do they go away?

Comment: Andrew, No They do not go away.